# How to extract values from xml using Powershell and XPath and based on the value search for the files if present or not

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, xpath, msbuild

> Problem:
>   I have this XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

> I have to write a function in Powershell, which check if all references in
>   the projects are valid (i.e. all referenced assemblies exist; you can
>   see them inside  block). Output both: all the
>   projects with invalid references and the invalid paths to assemblies.

So far I have tried this:

```
[xml]$results = Get-Content path-to-file/MigratorConsole.csproj

$fianl += $results.Project.ItemGroup.Reference | %{$_.HintPath} | select-object -unique

$fianl
$fianl.length
```

This is giving me the "HintPath" value but I am unable to get the matching "Project" value to check for what Project the HintPath is wrong or file is not present.

Please help!

Comment: I don't see any xpath usage in your post.  All you need to do is look at the include: `% { $_.HintPath + ' ' + $_.Include }`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1
Yes, It is giving me the Reference value as well. But, It is also giving those values to which there is no "HintPath" element as a child.
Means "<Reference Include="System" />" --> this was not expected to be print because there is no "HIntPath" element as a child to it.
How can we filter on the basis of where clause?
Means - where HintPath exists or where HintPath = <>

Comment: You can accomplish this by putting `| Where-Object { $_.HintPath } |` in the pipeline before `ForEach-Object`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1
Do you mean like this - $fianls += $results.Project.ItemGroup.Reference | %{$_.Include} | select-object -unique | Where-Object { $_.HintPath }
Sorry I am new to Powershell so my questions may sound dumb!

As per the question I want to get the Project name of the HinPath

Comment: In PowerShell, the mantra is filter left, format right.  `Where-Object` should be the first thing in the pipeline.

Comment: In my opinion you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job. A more correct approach would be to use MSBuild since it effectively evaluates the project file and as such will also fetch ProjectReferences from possibly imported projects, expand properties, etc. Whereas the PS way is limited to text-parsing only and as such will only find toplevel references and only work with full paths. So the solution might work for your particular simple use-case but could break easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stuffing your XML into a variable...

```
[xml]$foo = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>c:\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>c:\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
'@
```

I'm iterating over each project element. For each project, I'm pulling the references. If I find an invalid reference (path doesn't exist), I spit back a message saying invalid path and noting the project:

```
foreach ($project in $foo.project) {
    foreach ($reference in $project.ItemGroup.Reference) {
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($reference.HintPath) -eq $false) {
            if ( $(Test-Path -Path $reference.HintPath) -eq $false ) {
                Write-Output "Bad Path in $(${project}.Import.GetAttribute('Project'))"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure this isn't the info you want. The approach is kind-of what I want to show. I'm using multiple loops. One for the first entity you care about: project. Another for the second: reference paths. Hopefully this makes sense.

Good Luck,
A-

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Actually there is one problem here. My xml contains some more "import project" tags:

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(SlowCheetahTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(SlowCheetahTargets)')" Label="SlowCheetah" />

So these tags are also being fetched. And you can see there is no hintpath tag attached to these.

Comment: @Alex How to filter ==>Write-Output "Bad Path in $(${project}.Import.GetAttribute('Project'))"<=== with the $reference.HintPath that we are getting???